# Could users with enough reputation help review suggested edits and recommended closure flags?

Tags: discussion, moderation, review

I've been trying to review first posts/late answers as they come in, but suggested edits are going without review for a fair while.

I recognize that this site has fallen in activity, but we do have a fair few [suggested edits](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) pending that require review. Some of those that are pending appear to be tag wiki edits, which require an additional 500 reputation to review. I would lend my time to review them if I had the necessary reputation to do so, but alas...

In addition, the users who have reviewed the most suggested edits on this site are moderators, who already have other duties with flags and such. Two of them are moderators for many sites, which I'm sure takes away from the time they have to help day-to-day moderation for this site. While it would be nice if they continued to help out, we as users are given the ability to review for a reason, and should try and use that ability when possible. We shouldn't have to rely upon our diamond-clad users for everything.

A few of my recommend closure flags have aged away (one was, in retrospect, probably best.) The reputation threshold for casting close votes on this site is still 500, so a wider array of users should be able to help out here - even if the required closure threshold is at 5.

While Community Building looks like it's fading, I'd rather we went down swinging instead of just letting it fade away without trying.

Could users with the ability to do so lend a bit of their time to help review?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've been through the queues myself and approved most of the actions - suggested edits and closures - in case anyone's wondering why the queues are now almost empty.

There were a couple of suggested edits I was unsure about so I skipped those.

Because I moderate quite a few sites I don't always get time to check the review queues and have been neglecting it for a while, so if you see them build up again either raise a flag or a new meta question.